# How to change OpenGL Coordinate System + [Matrix operations]

Tags: opengl, matrix, system, axis, coordinate

I am creating 3D/2D graphics engine, I wrote some fancy Vector2, Vector3 classes, Window wrapper and OpenGL context creation framework and since a while I was thinking how can I switch Coordinate System axes. By default in OpenGL it goes like that (as far as I know):

```
+X axis stands for Right | -X for Left
+Y axis stands for Up    | -Y stands for Down
-Z stands for Forward    | -Z stands for Backward
```

I really, really do not want to have coords like that, it just makes for me coords unreadable. So I thought about that UE4-style coordinates:

```
+X axis stands for Forward
+Y axis stands for Right
+Z axis stands for Up
```

How can I switch these axes?

I've read about "tweaking" perspective but there was only inverting axis not switching them.

And my second question is where I can learn some matrix operations (straightly for computer graphics)? I do not want to download ready-to-use source code or extensions. The main purpose i write this engine is to learn maths and the most important thing for me now are matrixes - projection matrices, rotation matrices, translation matrices, scale etc.

Answer (score 2):

You are describing OpenGL's *clip space* coordinates and comparing it to UE4's *world space* coordinates.  In general, clip space and world space do not need to have any relationship to each other whatsoever, so it does not really make sense to compare them.

All you have to do is create a view matrix which converts your coordinates from world space to camera space.  This matrix is often combined with the conversion from model space to world space, and the matrix which converts from camera space to clip space.  Combining all three matrices gives you the "modelviewprojection" matrix.

Your vertex shader will end up looking something like this:

```
// In model space
in vec3 Coords;
// Conversion from model space to clip space
uniform mat4 MVP;

void main() {
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(Coords, 1.0);
}
```

MVP will be made out of a combination of rotation, translation, and scale matrices that work together.  The resulting matrix will probably look something like this:

> MVP = projection matrix * rotation matrix * translation matrix * scale matrix

The rotation matrix is the sauce that gets your axes right.  It will look something like this:

> rotation matrix = rotate around Z axis by (-roll) * rotate around X axis by (pitch + pi/2) * rotate around Z axis by (yaw - pi/2)

I suggest that you use the [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/) library, which provides the base vector and matrix types and operations in C++ that are provided for you in GLSL.  This lets you do linear algebra fairly easily.

I do not recommend trying to write these functions yourself.  It is mostly just a boring and repetitive programming task with lots of opportunities to make typos.  Speaking from experience.  Or, let me put it this way.  Making your own pencils does not make you a better writer.